# whktmltopdf error while opening PDF

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, frappe

I have installed whktmltopdf using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758589/wkhtmltopdf-installation-error-on-ubuntu).

Now it's throwing below error while opening pdf in Frappe framework.

```
raise IOError("wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code {0}. error:\n{1}".format(exit_code, stderr.decode("utf-8")))

IOError: wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code 1. error:
--no-outline specified in incorrect location

 Name:
 wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall wkhtmltopdf.

Steps to reinstall wkhtmltopdf on ubuntu 14.04

```
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltox
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
wkhtmltopdf -V
rm wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```